# Creating Rspec tests with Omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, omniauth

Rails noob here. I'm having trouble understanding how/what to test for regarding authentication with Omniauth-Facebook. Pretty much have a similar setup to the relevant railscast. I have my test environment set up similarly to what's described in previous questions and on the Gem wiki.

Couple of questions.  When you create a User factory how do you get resulting object to mock an authentication?

Also what goes on when the following code is run?

```
before do 
  request.env["omniauth.auth"] = OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:facebook]
  visit '/auth/facebook'
end
```

Is an object saved in a database?

I've added some sample specs below and the Factory spec. Again the `spec_helper` setup file has the test mode config set to true.

The `add_mock` setup:

```
OmniAuth.config.add_mock(:facebook,
                         { :provider => 'facebook',
                           :uid => '1234567',
                           :info => { :name => 'Jonathan', :image => 'http://graph.facebook.com/1234567/picture?type=square'},
                           :credentials => {
                             :expires_at => 1351270850,
                             :token=> 'AAADzk0b791YBAHCNhBI3n6ScmWvuXTY4yIUqXr9WiZCg1R808RYzaHxsHnrbn62IwrIgZCfSBZAVIP6ptF41nm8YtRtZCeBbxbbz1mF8RQZDZD'
                            } })
```

User_pages_spec:

```
describe "user pages" do

  let(:user) { Factory.create(:user) }

  describe "sign_in" do
    before { visit '/' }

    it "should add a user to the User model" do 
      expect { click_link "sign_in" }.to change(User, :count).by(1) 
    end

    it "should route to the appropriate page if email is nil" do
      click_link "sign_in"
      page.should have_selector('h5', text: 'Edit Email')
    end

    it "should redirect to the show page upon" do
      user.email = 'example@stanford.edu'
      user.save!
      click_link 'sign_in'
      page.should have_selector('div', text: user.name)
    end
   end
end
```

Factory

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    provider  "facebook"
    uid       '1234567'
    name      'Jonathan'
  end
end
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: Nope. Still having trouble understanding the substance behind what's going on

Comment: @rssathe Are you using Devise? If so, you might be missing some lines. Have you tried using the sample documented here? https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth/wiki/Integration-Testing